# how to auto change characters in Jtextfield using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a small project for school students. I want to show  some words like ***"apple"***,***"orange"*** etc. which words will come in `JTextField` while enter key using.The words must be come one by one. I have done small code for it but it is not working properly. It is showing only 1st word. Following is my code.

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    int c = 0;
    if (c==0)
    {
        jTextField1.setText("apple"); 
    }

    if (c==1)
    {
        jTextField1.setText("mango");
    }

    if (c==2)
    {
        jTextField1.setText("banana");
    }

    if (c==3)
    {
        jTextField1.setText("orange");
    }

    if (c==4)
    {
        jTextField1.setText("like");
    }

    if( c==5)
    {
        jTextField1.setText("it");
    }
   }
```

Comment: You always set `c to 0`, so the first condition is always true. I have no idea what "c" represents so I can't give you a suggestion on how to fix the problem. Maybe "c" should be an instance variable instead of a local variable and you just increment it by 1 every time the action is performed?

Comment: @camickr  so if I remove c  how the words will come one by one in Jtextfield ?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels can you share a sample code here ?

Comment: `if I remove c how the words will come one by one in Jtextfield ?` - I didn't suggest you remove it. I suggested you make it an instance variable (ie jTextField1 is an instance variable because you don't define the variable in the method). Then at the bottom of the method you just increment c by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your counter needs to be a field in your class, not a local variable. You should use either an array of String or `ArrayList<String>`, and use the counter to get the appropriate String from your collection.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    counter++;  // this is an instance field in the class.
    if (counter < myArray.length) {
        myTextField.setText(myArray[counter]);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please expand the full code. I have some mistakes . So I am thinking you will write full code

Comment: I am waiting for your reply

Comment: @user5840896 please don't ask for full code. We are volunteers and so the onus of effort should be yours. If you're still having trouble with your code, then much better would be for you to update your question, to show your latest code and to show and describe and all problems.

Comment: Where we can mention the count?